# Getting quick help information for Frama-C

Tags: frama-c

How to get quick help information for Frama-C (without having to resort to the manuals)? Typing "frama-c -help" displays very little useful data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of useful quick commands to obtain help, or to improve verbose/debug information when running `frama-c`:

- `frama-c -kernel-help`: the "actual" help page of the Frama-C kernel, with lots of useful options;
- `man frama-c`: very similar results to `frama-c -kernel-help`;
- `frama-c -kernel-msg-key help`: displays all *message categories* known by the kernel, used to produce verbose and debugging messages. They have no associated description, but a few are self-explanatory. For instance, `-kernel-msg-key pp` shows the actual preprocessing command used by Frama-C when parsing files;
- `frama-c -kernel-warn-key help`: lists all *warning categories*, plus their status (active, inactive, treat as error, abort immediately, warn once, etc);
- `frama-c -machdep help`: lists all available architectures known by Frama-C.

Each plug-in has its own `<plugin>-help`, `<plugin>-msg-key` and `<plugin>-warn-key`. It may also have extra "listing" options. For instance, the Eva (value analysis) plugin has option `-val-builtins-list`, which lists all available Eva built-ins and which function names are mapped to them.